# How to loop through a tags and redirect to retrieve more a tags?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

For educational purposes I am trying to write a program that would prompt the user for "url", "count" and "position".  The "url" will be scraped and "a tags" within the "url" will be retrieved and this would yield a list of "a tags". The "position" is then used to select a new link from the list of "a tags" previously retrieved and use it as the new "url" to be scraped. "Count" is the number of times this process takes place.

```
Code:
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bfs

# Declare global variables
href_list = []
no_iterations = 0

# Prompt user for input
url = raw_input('Enter url - ')
count = raw_input('Enter count - ')
position = raw_input('Enter position - ')

# While loop with condition
while no_iterations != int(count):
    no_iterations += 1

    # Scraping the url 
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bfs(html)

    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        href_list.append(tag.get('href', None))

    # Assiginig new url
    url = href_list[int(position)-1]

    # Printing info for user
    print 'Retrieving:', href_list[int(position)-1]
print 'Last Url:', href_list[int(position)-1]
```

When I run the program here is what I get:

```
Enter url - http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html 
Enter count - 4
Enter position - 3 

Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
Last Url: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
```

By observing the output, I can see that the URL is not reset as it should, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you arent incrementing `position` so it is always going to be the same. so `url = href_list[int(position)-1]` is always assigning url to the same url

Comment: You need to create new list. It is looking at the same list with same index so bound to find same URL. Even though you are appending the contents they will not overwrite original ones

Comment: Got it, I reset the href_list = [] after declaring the new URL and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by resetting the list were I stored the retrieved a tags
Code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bfs

# Declare global variables
href_list = []
no_iterations = 0

# Prompt user for input
url = raw_input('Enter url - ')
count = raw_input('Enter count - ')
position = raw_input('Enter position - ')

# While loop with condition
    while no_iterations != int(count):
    no_iterations += 1

    # Scraping the url 
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bfs(html)

    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        href_list.append(tag.get('href', None))

    # Assiginig new url
    url = href_list[int(position)-1]
    href_list = []
    # Printing info for user
    print 'Retrieving:', href_list[int(position)-1]
print 'Last Url:', url
```

So the new output now is:

```
Enter url - http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html 
Enter count - 4
Enter position - 3
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Mhairade.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Butchi.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Anayah.html
Last Url: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Anayah.html
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

**Modified[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo4Jd.png) code and working one!**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bfs
#global variables
href_list = []
no_iterations = 0
# Prompt user for input
url = input('Enter url:')
count = input('Enter no. of iterations: ')
position = input('Enter start position ')
# While loop with condition
while no_iterations != int(count):
    no_iterations += 1
    # Scraping the url 
    soup = bfs((urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()),'html.parser')
    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        href_list.append(tag.get('href'))
    # Assiginig new url
    url = href_list[int(position)-1]
     # Printing info for user
    print ('Retrieving:', url)
    href_list = []
print ('Last Url:', url)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code, could you please elaborate on what you've changed, and why?

Comment: Changed the order of  2 lines :  print ('Retrieving:', url)  and 
    href_list = []     (if you empty the list href_list[]  first,then the line 'Retrieving:' url will have [] (empty list) output)