# Python 3.0/Beautifulsoup: Looping through parsed data choose a specific link open that link and repeat

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to do the following: read trough a website choose the 18 th of link on this site, open that link and repeat that 7 times. But I am not really advanced in programming, so I stuck by trying to open the 18th link. How can I do that?  My code is this:

```
import urllib.request
import io
u = urllib.request.urlopen("http://xxxxxxxx.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Yong.html", data = None)
f = io.TextIOWrapper(u, encoding='utf-8')
text = f.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
print (soup.find_all("a")
```

my result looks like this: e.g

```
[ href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Keiva.html">Keiva</a>, href="http://xxxxx.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Rowyn.</a>]
```

An HTML-document with names/links.

Till I not expect, that anybody is guiding me trough the whole code, where can I look up what I need?

Here are my main questions:

1. How can I make the program count the names/links?
2. How can I open the 18th link in the list?
3. How can I repeat that,7 times?

Thanks for your support in advance!!

Comment: Please see if this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459374/automatizing-a-python-web-crawler-how-to-prevent-raw-input-all-the-time

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423040/how-to-loop-through-a-tags-and-redirect-to-retrieve-more-a-tags

Comment: Great, I will try this. Thanks for your fast reply!